# create rails migration for PostgreSQL GENERATED ALWAYS AS column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-migrations

How to create rails migration for auto calculated columns like below.

```
    a_column integer,
    b_column integer,
    total1 integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS (a_column+b_column) stored,
    total2 integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS (a_column-b_column) stored,
    total3 integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS (a_column/b_column) stored
);
```

I don't want to do using Models,
because I want to use same table from another system having different technology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pure SQL in migration

```
def up
  execute <<~SQL
    CREATE TABLE table_name (
      a_column integer,
      b_column integer,
      total1 integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS (a_column+b_column) stored,
      total2 integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS (a_column-b_column) stored,
      total3 integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS (a_column/b_column) stored
    );
  SQL
end

def down
  drop_table :table_name
end
```

When using such migrations, in order for the database schema to be correct, you need to use SQL dump type (default type is Ruby). To setup this setting add line to your `config/application.rb`

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

After that schema will be saved to `db/structure.sql`

Please [read more](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you)

Comment: You should also change the schema dumps to SQL instead of `schema.rb` or the information will get lost or it might blow up. https://blog.appsignal.com/2020/01/15/the-pros-and-cons-of-using-structure-sql-in-your-ruby-on-rails-application.html

Comment: Thanks @max. I added information to the answer